# How to count specific elements in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object which looks like this:

```
var allDataJson = [{"Researchers":"Laura, Mikael","Year":"2015"}, 
{"Researchers":"Mikko","Year":"2013",}, 
{"Researchers":"Harri","Year":"2015"}, .......] //long list
```

I need to create a JSON object as follows:

```
 var myjson = [{"Year": 2015, "Total":60}, 
                  {"Year": 2014, "Total":68},
                  {"Year": 2013, "Total":72}]
```

For instance there are 60 `allDataJson` items with Year 2015.

So far I only could get the year values. Any ideas about how to calculate `Total`?

Here is my code:

```
function countPublicationsPerYear(allDataJson){
    var lookup = {};
    var items = allDataJson;
    var result = [];

    for (var item, i = 0; item = items[i++];) {
        var year = item.Year;
        count ++;
        if (!(year in lookup)) {
            var count = Object.keys(item).length;
            lookup[year] = 1;
            result.push({ "Year":year
            });
        }
    }
    return result; //returns Year: 2013, 2014, 2015
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are trying to add total number of researchers ?

**Answer**

```
function countPublicationsPerYear(allDataJson){
    var lookup = {};
    var items = allDataJson;
    var result = [];

    for (var item, i = 0; item = items[i++];) {
        var year = item.Year;
        count ++;
        if (!(year in lookup)) {
            lookup[year] = 1;
        } else {
            lookup[year]++;
        }
    }

    for (var property in lookup) {
        if (lookup.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            result.push({"Year": property, "Total": lookup[property]});
        }
    }

    return result; //returns Year: 2013, 2014, 2015
}
```

```js
var allDataJson = [{"Researchers":"Laura, Mikael","Year":"2015"}, 
{"Researchers":"Mikko","Year":"2013",}, 
{"Researchers":"Harri","Year":"2015"}];

function countPublicationsPerYear(allDataJson){
        var lookup = {};
        var items = allDataJson;
        var result = [];
    
        for (var item, i = 0; item = items[i++];) {
            var year = item.Year;
            if (!(year in lookup)) {
                lookup[year] = 1;
            } else {
                lookup[year]++;
            }
        }
    
        for (var property in lookup) {
            if (lookup.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                result.push({"Year": property, "Total": lookup[property]});
            }
        }
    
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
  
        return result; //returns Year: 2013, 2014, 2015
    }

countPublicationsPerYear(allDataJson);
```

Comment: That prints the first object matching with 2013, 2014, 2015. I need to count how many times those years occurred.

Comment: No, I'm trying to find how many times publications happened in year 2015. `var allDataJson = [{"Researchers":"Laura, Mikael","Year":"2015"}, 
{"Researchers":"Mikko","Year":"2013",}, 
{"Researchers":"Harri","Year":"2015"}]` in here 2015 would have total value of 2 for example.

Comment: I asked similar question which I think you could solve. I would be glad if you could take a look @Vigneswaran Marimuthu. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29683863/counting-certain-json-elements

Comment: @supaplex Sure will do :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
var count = {};
for (var x = 0; x < allDataJson.length; x++) {
    var current = allDataJson[x];
    if (!count[current["Year"]]) count[current["Year"]] = 1;
    else
        count[current["Year"]] = count[current["Year"]] + 1;
}

var result = []
for(key in count){
    result.push({
        "Year" : key,
        "Total" : count[key]
    })
}

console.log(result) //prints [{"Year":"2013","Total":1},{"Year":"2015","Total":2}]
```

see fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing this snippet for you:

```
var totals = {};
for (var i=0; i<allDataJson.length; i++) {
    var researchYear = allDataJson[i].Year;
  if (researchYear in totals){ 
    totals[researchYear]++;
  } else {
    totals[researchYear] = 1;
  }
 };
console.log(totals); // your years summaries
console.log(JSON.stringify(totals)); //as json
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var allDataJson = [{"Researchers":"Laura, Mikael","Year":"2015"}, 
{"Researchers":"Mikko","Year":"2013"}, 
{"Researchers":"Harri","Year":"2015"},
{"Researchers":"Mikko","Year":"2013"}, 
{"Researchers":"Harri","Year":"2015"},{"Researchers":"Mikko","Year":"2013"}, 
{"Researchers":"Harri","Year":"2015"},{"Researchers":"Mikko","Year":"2013"}, 
{"Researchers":"Harri","Year":"2015"},{"Researchers":"Mikko","Year":"2013"}, 
{"Researchers":"Harri","Year":"2015"}];
var your_array=[];
var counts = {};
$.each(allDataJson, function (key, vale) {
    your_array.push(vale.Year);
});
your_array.forEach(function(x) { 
    counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0)+1;
});
alert(JSON.stringify(counts));
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u7dqe4ak/)